# Required attribute for the selector tag?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm porting some projects over from Eclipse to Android Studio and in one I'm sorting through various XML errors and in one file I have...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/downarrow_pressed"
           android:state_pressed="true" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/downarrow_normal" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

... and Android Studio is saying that the selector tag is missing two required attributes: layout_height and layout_width.

Three questions:

1. What are the correct values for those attributes in this context?
2. Why didn't Eclipse flag this? (it builds and runs fine from Eclipse)
3. I've been searching through developer.android.com and I can't seem to figure out where to tell what the required attributes for a tag are.  Where is that?

Comment: `selector` does not have `layout_width` or `layout_height`. If you get that error, then it thinks you are trying to load that file as a layout, not a drawable resource. Refer: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: Where is the above XML file is located in your project ?

Comment: `... and Android Studio is saying that the selector tag is missing two required attributes: layout_height and layout_width.` I rather guess it tells you that the selector **in the layout file** is missing those attributes.

Comment: @rotwang the message is _Element selector doesn't have required attribute:layout_height_

Comment: Yes. ... and? it refers to the selector you have in your xml layout. Which makes sense, because it's the only place where `layout_width` and `layout_height` can be set.

Answer (score 0):

#3 -- [Documentation is here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

The only requirement for a `selector` tag is the `xmlns:android`, which can only be that one string value.

`<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

This can have many `<item>` elements, where the only requirement is a `android:drawable`.

I think that error is refering to the layout that contains this selector drawable, or you've misread the error. Eclipse didn't flag it because Eclipse does not run the Gradle tasks like `lint`.

Comment: the text of the error message is, " Element selector doesn't have required attribute:layout_height", and it's shown as an error, not a warning

Comment: I looked at your documentation link and I don't see where it says that layout_height is a required attribute for element selector.  How would I derive that requirement from the documentation you linked to?

Comment: It doesn't have that attribute, as I said. You should edit your question with a screen shot. If you think it's a bug, then you can report that on the Android Studio site